# Sql Query on Union on specific column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

```
T1: Schema(Bucket_Id,B_Id);<br>
T2: Schema(B_Id,V_Id);<br>
```

Relations:

```
R1: Bucket_Id->B_Id (one to many)<br>
R2: B_Id->V_Id (one to many)<br>
```

I want to have all the B_Id OR V_Id corresponding to a given Bucket_Id.
Can someone help me with this.

Thanks

Example:
Table T1

```
Bucket_Id      B_Id
b1             B1
b1             B2
b2             B3
b2             B4
```

Table T2

```
B_Id           V_Id
B1             V1
B1             V2
B3             V3
B3             V4
```

Expected Output

```
b1             B1
b1             V1
b1             V2
b1             B2
b2             B3
b2             V3
b2             V4
b2             B4
```

Comment: In your example simple union will give that result. Can you give a more complicated test data that would show difficulty of this task?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM T1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM T2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
select * from T1
union all 
select T1.Bucket_id ,V_Id 
from T1 join T2 on T1.B_Id = T2.B_Id
```